# Multiplication versus Addition in Counting

Tags: combinatorics

Five teams have to compete in a league, with every team playing every other team exactly once, before going to the next round. How many matches will have to be held to complete the league round to matches?

My attempt: 4*3*2*1=24.

But the answer is given as 4+3+2+1=10.

I guess I had learnt that for simultaneous events, we multiply. For independent events, we add. The above scenario looks like a simultaneous one to me. What is wrong in this line of thinking?

I always make mistake in such questions. Is there a general way to decide when to go for multiplication and when addition? Or is there any solid line of thinking that one should adhere to while attempting such questions?

Thanks.

Comment: That's incorrect. For example, if there are four parties happening simultaneously, multiplying them together to figure out the total number of parties would give you 1·1·1·1.

Comment: Draw a table. What do you see?

Answer (score 1):

What you are counting is how many different ways are there to arrange matches for a single team ($4$ choices in first round, $3$ in the second,...) what they are asking is how many games, in total. To visualize this, you can draw 5 points (teams) on a piece of paper and every time you connect a point to another, you say that these two teams have played each other. The first point will have four others to connect to, the second point will have three (since it is already connected to the first) and so on. How many connections are there after all points have been matched?